# SMTP Error: Failure Sending Email

Tags: silverlight, email, silverlight-4.0, smtp, smtpclient

I've downloaded a sample application sending email silverlight application here.

via gmail. But I cant make it work. Its error is "Failure sending mail."

> {"Failure sending mail."}
>       [System.Net.Mail.SmtpException]: {"Failure sending mail."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}
>       Message: "Failure sending mail."
>       Source: "System"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)\r\n   at SLSentEmail.Web.Services.EmailService.SendEmail(SLEmailMessage emailMessage) in C:\Downloads\Temp\SLSentEmail\SLSentEmail\SLSentEmail.Web\Services\EmailService.svc.cs:line 27"
>       TargetSite: {Void Send(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your setup or code, I would look into the inner exception - "Unable to connect to the remote server".

Do you actually have access to the SMTP server?

Could there be a block due to a system or network firewall?
Some ISPs block port 25 in order to stop bot spamming, you may need to connect via a different port.